# How do I move unallocated, non-adjacent space to another partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

My current partitions are [as such,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6xD2.png) where sda7 is my swap partition and sd8 is my Ubuntu partition. I want to merge my unallocated space to sda8 but there are two partitions (sda5 and sda6) in between.

My current plan is to shift the two partitions to the left and merge the unallocated space to sda8. But when I tried to do that, GParted warned me that my system may fail to boot.

Is it possible to do that despite the warning? How do I know if sda5 and sda6 are movable?

Comment: Apparently your disk holds a Windows installation. Windows is (or at least, it used to be) very sensitive to the physical location of partitions on disk. If I were you I would first back up all important data which may be present in Windows, then use a Windows-based tool such as MiniTools Partition Wizard to move the Windows partitions.

Comment: I see. My Windows 10 install got bricked by a rogue Samsung software update, though, so I can't use a Windows-based tool to do partitioning. I also don't really care about losing all my installed programs. (I have backups of all important files though.) 

In this case, would proceeding with GParted and shifting the two partitions to the left be okay? I'm more concerned with my Ubuntu install. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Partitions are mapped to physical locations on the drive. You can expand and shrink them, but cannot "move" them in the sense you seem to want. Note that ANY change to partitions risks TOTAL DATA LOSS, so backups are a good idea.

Comment: If your Win10 install is 'bricked', then why fiddle with partitions at all? You have a golden opportunity to backup your data, then nuke the entire drive and install Ubuntu. Preserve your Win10 Key, of course. Win10 works very well in a VM.